# Why does dual-tree complex wavelet have shift invariant?

Tags: wavelet

I recently learned about the definition of shift invariant, but I still don’t understand why does the dual-tree complex wavelet transform have this property. Can someone explain it simply?

Answer (score 0):

The short explanation is that the DTCWT is not exactly shift-invariant. A shift-invariant invertible wavelet transform is the à trous algorithm, also called cycle spinning (see an overview [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1016/j.sigpro.2009.11.022)). The principle behind the DTCWT is explained [here](https://people.math.sc.edu/blanco/IMI/DTCWT0.pdf) in a very accessible way.

Compared to the FFT, the DWT is not shift invariant because at each scale, the odd samples are treated very differently from the even samples. In the frequency domain, the even samples are covered by the real part, the odd samples by the imaginary part.

The DTCWT paper explains that following this principle, a shift invariant transform can be built, but not with compact basis functions (localised in time). The DTCWT uses basis functions that are compact and as close to shift-invariant as possible.